# PHP code inside shortcodes

Tags: php, functions, shortcode, mysql

Basically, I have this line of code:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[O_U user_name="operator" 
blocked_message="This page is restricted for guests."] 
**Content Goes here** [/O_U]'); ?>
```

Now, inside Content Goes here I use regular HTML to create my content. But, now, I need to add some php inside that HTML.

Right now, I need to populate the *option* for **select** tag with MySQL results.

I have a php code:

```
<?php
        $database_name = "rams";
        $mydb = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, $database_name, DB_HOST);
        $mydb -> show_errors();

        //Populate languages
        $languages = $mydb -> get_results(
            'SELECT * FROM language_skills'
        );

        foreach ($languages as $language){
           //do some echo of html
        }
?>
```

How can I achieve a result here? I now, echo waits for a string there. I thought about heredoc and a custom function, but I can't seem to achieve the result.

**UPDATE:**

I managed to get my data. It's in an array. How I can show all the array results in above situation?

My array goes something like this:

```
<option value="$value">$content</option>
```

It shows exactly what I want when I use:

```
[shortcode].$array[index].[/shortcode]
```

How can I add all the indexes? I tried for each but it doesn't work in between shortcodes

ANSWER:

I used implode to change array to a string and code now works as i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not put PHP functions inside your shortcode.

However, you do not need to. You can just use your `foreach`-loop to create the html and store it in a variable, for example `$shortcodehtml`.

So, afterwards, you can call

```
echo do_shortcode('[O_U user_name="operator" blocked_message="This page is restricted for guests."]' . $shortcodehtml . '[/O_U]');
```

The better version of that would be if you would create the output inside the shortcode function - from my point of view it is not necessary to pass the whole html to the shortcode - but this should work fine.

Comment: Can you please ellaborate the answer? You mean I should store foreach results in an array and then pass it as above?

Comment: I can't seem to make it work. I've created an array of option tags and it displays when I use echo the array. but it doesn't work in above fashion

Answer (score 1):

It's always better to use the `PHP` stuff inside your function definition and not while executing your shortcode.

To add more to Fischi's answer, you can refer to below snippet.

```
function wptuts_first_shortcode($atts, $content=null){

    $return_variable = "";
    $database_name = "rams";
    $mydb = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, $database_name, DB_HOST);
    $mydb -> show_errors();

    //Populate languages
    $languages = $mydb -> get_results(
        'SELECT * FROM language_skills'
    );

    foreach ($languages as $language){
       $return_variable = $return_variable."<br />".$language;
    }
    return $return_variable;
  }

add_shortcode($return_variable, 'wptuts_first_shortcode');
```

You can use the returned value in your shortcode display.

Refer the [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/getting-started-with-wordpress-shortcodes--wp-21197) for additional reference.